# Script to extract current Google Maps destination

Tags: android, google-maps, tasker

I'm working on a Tasker script (sqlite or other) to extract the current destination from Google Maps navigation and send it to another device.

1. Could someone please direct me to the appropriate Android GMaps database that contains the current destination address/coordinates when navigating using GMaps?
2. Could you please suggest a script to extract the current destination into Tasker.

I've tried a suggestion (2012 forum post) to run the following script:

```
sqlite3 /data/data/com.google.android.apps.maps/databases/da_destination_history  "select dest_address from destination_history order by time desc limit 1;"
```

Unfortunately this script seems dated as I can't find the database da_destination_history in the files of the latest iteration of Gmaps.

Out of the GMaps databases I have found, gmm_storage.db does seem to contain the current destination address, but I can't find a way of identifying it as such within the file, thereby allowing operations to recognise and extract the destination address.